# Qual está sendo a razão de um runtime error neste código?

Tags: c, árvore-binária

Tenho um exercício para fazer e submeto ele para um corretor automático (Sharif), nos meus testes todos os casos dão certo, porém no corretor estou recebendo um Runtime Error, já revi esse código muitas vezes e não acho o erro. (O detalhamento exagerado é justamente pelo fato de tentar achar o erro)

## Problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "operations.h"

int main (){
    int num;
    char buffer;
    treeNode * arvore = NULL;

    while(1){
        // Lê a operação
        scanf("%c",&buffer);
        // Vê se deseja sair
        if(buffer == 'S') break;
        // Verifica as operações
        if(buffer == 'I'){ // Inserção
            //Lê o número para inserir
            scanf("%d",&num);
            // Insere o número na árvore
            insert(&arvore,num);
        }else if(buffer == 'R'){ //Remoção
            //Lê o número para remoção
            scanf("%d",&num);
            // Deleta o nó
            deleteNode(&arvore,num);
        }else if (buffer == 'M'){ //Mostra árvore
            inOrd(&arvore);
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

## Biblioteca de operações

```
#ifndef OPERATIONS
#define OPERATIONS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TreeNode{
    int data;
    struct TreeNode * esq;
    struct TreeNode * dir;
};

//Definição dos dados
typedef struct TreeNode treeNode;
typedef struct TreeNode ** root;

//Definição das funções
treeNode * createNode();
void inOrd(root Tree);
void insert(root Tree,int data);
void deleteNode(root Tree,int data);
treeNode * pai(root Tree, int data);
treeNode * busca(root Tree,int data);
treeNode * maisDireita(root Tree);

//Implementação das funções
treeNode * createNode(){
    treeNode * newNode;
    newNode = (treeNode*) malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    newNode->data = 0;
    return newNode;
}

void inOrd(root Tree){
    if(*Tree == NULL) return;

    inOrd(&((*Tree)->esq));
    printf("%d ",(*Tree)->data);
    inOrd(&((*Tree)->dir));

}

void insert(root Tree,int data){
    // Caso a raiz da árvore seja nula
    if((*Tree) == NULL){
        // Cria o nó para ser adicionado a árvore
        treeNode * newNode = createNode();
        // Copia o dado para o nó criado
        newNode->data = data;
        // Coloca esse novo nó na raiz da árvore
        (*Tree) = newNode;
        return;
    }
    // Caso o dado a ser inserido seja menor que o dado atual da árvore
    if(data < (*Tree)->data)
        insert(&((*Tree)->esq),data);
    // Caso o dado a ser inserido seja maior que o dado atual da árvore
    else
        insert(&((*Tree)->dir),data);
}

void deleteNode(root Tree,int data){
    /*****************************************
    * Temos três casos para se deletar um nó:*
    *    1 - Se o nó é uma folha.            *
    *    2 - Se o nó tem somente um filho.   *
    *    3 - Se o nó tem dois filhos.        *
    *                                        *
    *****************************************/

    //Antes de qualquer caso verificamos se a árvore não é nula.
    if((*Tree) == NULL)
        return;

    // Procuramos o nó que queremos remover.
    treeNode * temp;
    temp = busca(Tree,data);

    /*
    Caso 1:
        Neste caso, para se remover um nó k, fazemos com que o pai de k, p(k) aponte para NULL e excluimos
        o próprio nó. 
    */
    if(temp->esq == NULL && temp->dir == NULL){
        treeNode * paiNode;
        // Acha o pai do nó que queremos remover
        paiNode = pai(Tree,data);
        // Vê se o nó que queremos remover é o da esquerda ou o da direita
        // Esquerda
        printf("%d\n",paiNode->data);
        if (paiNode->esq != NULL){
            if (paiNode->esq->data == data){
                free(paiNode->esq);
                paiNode->esq = NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        // Direita
        if (paiNode->dir != NULL){
            if(paiNode->dir->data == data){
                free(paiNode->dir);
                paiNode->dir = NULL;
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    /*
    Caso 2:
        Neste caso o nó tem apenas um filho, basicamente fazemos o pai de k apontar para o filho de k
    */

    // Ele tem somente um filho a direita
    if(temp->esq == NULL && temp->dir != NULL){
        treeNode * paiNode = pai(Tree,data);
        // Faz com que o filho da direita do pai de temp se torne o filho de temp
        paiNode->dir = temp->dir;
        // Libera o nó que queremos remover
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    // Tendo somente um filho a esquerda
    if(temp->esq != NULL && temp->dir == NULL){
        treeNode * paiNode = pai(Tree,data);
        // Faz com que o filho da direita do pai de temp se torne o filho de temp
        paiNode->esq = temp->esq;
        // Libera o nó que queremos remover
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    /*
    Caso 3:
        Neste caso o nó tem dois filhos, procuramos o filho mais a direita da sub-árvore a esquerda e
        substituimos os dados dele e liberamos esta folha
    */
    if (temp->esq != NULL && temp->dir != NULL){
        int aux;
        // Acho o nó mais a direita da sub-árvore a esquerda
        treeNode * direita = maisDireita(&(temp->esq));
        // Salva o dado do ponteiro direita em um inteiro auxiliar 
        aux = direita->data;
        // Deleta o nó mais a direita
        deleteNode(Tree,direita->data);
        // Transfere o dado para a o nó que deveria ser "removido"
        temp->data = aux;
    }

}

treeNode * pai(root Tree, int data){
    // So realizamos operações se a árvore não for nula
    if(*Tree != NULL){
        treeNode * temp;
        temp = *Tree;
        // Verifica se o nó a direita ou a esquerda é igual ao nó que desejamos procurar, caso seja
        // retorna ele
        if (temp->esq != NULL)
            if (temp->esq->data == data)
                return temp;
        if (temp->dir != NULL)
            if (temp->dir->data == data)
                return temp;
        // Procura na sub-árvore a esquerda caso o dado seja menor do que o que está no nó.
        if (data < temp->data)
            pai(&(temp->esq),data);
        // Procura na sub-árvore a direita caso o dado seja maior do que o que está no nó.
        else if (data > temp->data)
            pai(&(temp->dir),data);
    }
}

treeNode * busca(root Tree,int data){
    // Verifica se a árvore não é vazia
    if (*Tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // Checa se o dado do nó é o dado que estamos procurando
    if ((*Tree)->data == data)
        return (*Tree);
    // Caso não seja:
    // Se o dado for menor do que o dado atual, vai para a árvore da esquerda
    if (data < (*Tree)->data)
        busca(&((*Tree)->esq),data);
    // Caso contrário vai para a árvore da direita
    else
        busca(&((*Tree)->dir),data);
}

treeNode * maisDireita(root Tree){
    // Verificamos se a árvore não é vazia
    if(*Tree != NULL){
        treeNode * temp = (*Tree);
        // Caminha até o filho mais a direita
        while(temp->dir != NULL){
            temp = temp->dir;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

#endif
```

## Minha saida

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Runtime Error ==> RTE. Isso é devido ao programa sair com um código não 0. Isso normalmente é devido a alguma falha de segmentação ou então outra coisa que causou ao seu programa a abortar. Outros erros de programação competitiva (como é o exemplo desse sistema de submissão) são: Compilation Error (não consegue compilar o fonte), Presentation Error (o conteúdo da resposta está certo, mas ele não está sendo apresentado de maneira correta), Wrong Answer (resposta errada) e Time Limit Exceeded(TLE, programa muito lento, o sistema nem conseguiu julgar se ele estava errando as respostas)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Realmente, o problema era esse, o fato de faltar o `return 0` no final da main.

Comment: Eu sempre pensei que o G++ colocava um `return 0` implícito ao final da `main`. Mas, enfim, fico feliz que tenha corrigido